# RGB matrix 32x16 connected to ESP32 shows only upper half part

Tags: esp32, led-matrix

I have

1. [32x16 RGB matrix](https://www.adafruit.com/product/420)
2. ESP32 WROOM-32
3. Power supply for the matrix 5V, 5A

I used [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mF9df4QYprU) to connect them. I just changed some wires. Here is my connection:

[image: ESP32 and RGB matrix connection]

In text:

Upper RGB Data

- R1 - G25
- G1 - G26
- B1 - G27

Lower RGB Data

- R2 - G32
- G2 - G33
- B2 - G34

Row Select Lines

- A - G21 (yellow)
- B - G22 (grey)
- C - G23 (purple)

LAT Wire

- LAT (STB) - G4 (white)

OE Wire

- OE - G17 (Blue)

CLK Wire

- CLK -16 (brown)

The code example:

```
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h>

#define CLK  16
#define OE   17
#define LAT 4
#define A   21
#define B   22
#define C   23

uint8_t pins[] = {25, 26, 27, 32, 33, 34};

// Last parameter = 'true' enables double-buffering, for flicker-free,
// buttery smooth animation.  Note that NOTHING WILL SHOW ON THE DISPLAY
// until the first call to swapBuffers().  This is normal.
RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, CLK, LAT, OE, false, pins);


unsigned char x, y;
bool show;

void setup() {
  matrix.begin();
}


void loop() {
  matrix.fillScreen(0xffff);
  //matrix.swapBuffers(true);
}
```

This example of code fills the first half of the matrix.

I used the "RGB matrix panel" library from Adafruit. The example `plasma_16x32` as well showed me just the upper part of the matrix. Here is the result:

[image: half matrix]

I thought that the D connection could be an issue, however, for the 32x16 matrix (according to the official description) it should be connected to the ground (as I did). I checked all wires with my tester and all is good.

How could I debug it? Is there a way to check the matrix? Maybe it's broken.

Comment: You don't show your code, but have you taken into account that the panel in the video is 128X64 and yours is 32X16?

Comment: `How could I debug it?` ... swap upper and lower lines ... swap row select lines around

Comment: Adafruit: `There's no “official” documention out there on how these matrices work` - oh, great. How many pixels do you "CLK" in before getting them "LAT"ched? It should be no less than 64, with only the last 64 displayed once latched.

Comment: (`How could I debug it?` find someone you can swap display&"test-bed" with: run your display in a known working environment; run a known working display in your environment (maybe using the known good PS).)

Comment: @PeterJennings Sorry, I've just added a simple example of code that should fill the matrix with white LEDs, however, it fills just the upper part.

Comment: @greybeard I use the Adafruit library. I can't tell you how many pixels.

Comment: @jsotola I swapped cables and: for RGB I saw that colours changed, for ABC lines - with a filled matrix nothing changed, however, if I print some text, changing lines just brake it. But still in the upper part of the matrix.

Comment: Swap the 3 "Upper RGB" and "Lower RGB" data lines over and see if you then get stuff on the lower set and nothing on the upper instead. That would indicate if you have a problem with driving the "Lower RGB" data lines.

Comment: @brhans thanks a lot for the idea. I showed a text in the middle of the matrix (I had only half of the text), I swapped R1, G1, and B1 with R2, G2 and B2 and I got the lower part of the text on the upper part of the matrix. Does it mean that matrix is broken?

Comment: It would seems so - I can't think of any better explanation off-hand.